# Safari 10.1 – text-align: justify text goes outside the border in RTL languages

Tags: html, css, safari, text-align, justify

I have HTML markup with a text paragraph in the `body` element. In the CSS stylesheet, I added:

```
body {
  text-align: justify;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 23;

  letter-spacing:0.05pt;
  line-height: 125%;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  margin: 0.00em 20em;
  text-indent: 0em; 
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

When I load it in Safari 10.1, the text goes outside of the body border. But the same markup in an older version of Safari (10.0) works fine and in Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (x86_64).

How do I fix the markup and style in order for this to work in the new Safari?

Comment: Can you be more specific? This looks OK to me except in a narrow viewport, but that's because of your `20em` left and right `margin`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdxYVW

Comment: Maybe you just need to set a different kind of relative width on `body` and use left/right `margin: auto` to center it? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmKQMg

Comment: This problem exists for right-to-left languages like Arabic

Comment: Please edit the question to say that the problem is specific to right-to-left languages. Thank you!

Comment: @Multithreader is right. After testing it seems to not occur with latin characters, but arabic characters for example. See a Pen of the problem here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwvWbJ and a **screenshot** here: https://imgur.com/a/YzsGP

Answer (score 4):

it's officially a safari 10.1 bug.
you can rate this post on apple communities maybe they fix it sooner . 
[safari 10.1 text-align: justify Bug](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7912165)

Comment: The OP asked a question for a solution and not the bug he actually opened...A possible solution or a hack is what he need

Comment: I don’t think there is a hack, @OhadM. I researched this problem, too. No fix in sight. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184042/ios-10-3-safari-text-alignjustify-bug-for-persian-arabic-content

Comment: This is why there is a bounty :)