# iOS 10.3 safari text-align:justify bug for Persian/Arabic content

Tags: css, text-align, persian

My website was working and viewing well on every mobile browser of my iPhone before updating to 10.3. From the time I updated my iOS to 10.3, my content page faced an issue:

Content is wrapped in a `<div>` with CSS property of `text-align: justify`. My content is in [Persian (Farsi)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_language).

**The problem is:** my text content overflows container and when I add a `padding` to the container to see if it is just overflowed, I found out that it isn't rendering it *justified* and it's showing it *right aligned*.

Is there anyone with this issue? Can anyone help?

**Update** I've added a codepen example: [Click Here To Open Codepen](http://codepen.io/webgodo/pen/wJOEaJ/)

**Update** As you can see in the following screenshot, the red text is overflowed to the left sidebar:

[image: Screenshot of overflowed justified text]

Comment: Finally fixed in update 10.3.2

Answer (score 0):

it's officially a safari 10.1 bug . things worked fine on older safari .

chrome and other browser worked fine in same device .

you can rate this post on apple communities maybe they fix it sooner .
[safari 10.1 text-align: justify Bug](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7912165)

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily fix this problem by adding this code to your css:

```css
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) { @media {
    .main { 
         text-align: right!important; 
    }
}}
```